# fetch presigned url to s3 by put getting forbidden 403

Tags: amazon-s3, put, pre-signed-url

I'm using Amazon S3 to store images and I'm generating a pre-signed URL to upload them. When I use Python to upload the images using the pre-signed URL, it works without any issues. However, when I try to do the same using JavaScript (as part of a React app), I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// input-file (saved into img state var)
<input id="id_img1" type="file" accept="image/*"
        onChange={(e) => {setImg(e.target.files[0]);}} />

// on submit:
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('File', img)

options = {
    method: 'put',
    body: fd,
}
res = await fetch(psurl, options)
```

I've read that adding a Content-Type header to the request may help, but when I tried it, it didn't solve the issue.

I also tried to set the image into the body as:

```
body: img
// or
body: img["file"]
```

And still, no success.

The pre-signed URL is valid and I'm able to upload images to the same S3 bucket using Python, but not with JavaScript. What could be causing the 403 Forbidden error and how can I resolve it?

The python code I used is:

```
requests.put(url=psurl, data=open(image_path, 'rb'))
```

I spent too much time on it, and I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to solve the issue by adding "ContentType" at the server side.

```
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': object_key,
            'ContentLength': max_size,
            'ContentType': "image/jpeg",   // I added this
        },
        ExpiresIn=expiration
    )
```